# Merge separate git repositories into one repository, organized by folders

Tags: git, github, merge, directory, repository

I am trying to organize my projects folder which has all the [/r/dailyprogrammer](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer) challenges I've attempted. Currently, each challenge has into own respective folder and thus its own git repo.

What I'd like to do is make one large repo and merge all my challenges into their own folder inside the large repo. That way on GitHub I don't have a million different repos; rather in one large repo, organized in folders.

Here's my current folder structure containing all the small git repos:

```
   .
   |-201PracticalExcerise
   |-204Hard
   |-204Intermediate
   |-214Hard
   |-215Easy
   |-215Intermediate
   |-218Easy
```

I tried following [this guide](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/merge-two-git-repositories-into-one/). But every time I do the merge, the files from within the git repos would be copied over to the root of the large repo. Then when I moved those files into their own folder, I lost the commit history.

I could not figure out how to get the files to go into separate folders.

**How can I take each folder above, merge them into one large repo with their respective commit histories and their own folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to follow the comment in the guide:

> Be sure to create at least one initial commit prior to doing the
>   sub-tree merges.

If that doesn't work you might try doing the following:

- for each repo, make a commit putting the code in a subdirectory like you eventually want
- then, follow the tutorial

For example, in 201PracticalExcerise repo, do the following:

- `mkdir 201PracticalExcerise`
- `git mv [all files at root level] 201PracticalExcerise`

Then repeat for each one (so they're already in the right subdirectories).

I'd try it on a couple first just to see if it works.

Comment: So do a `git mv` on each file in each repo?

Comment: Hope I clarified my intent.  I haven't tried it, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested. But at the step in the tutorial which says to do a `git read-tree`, it creates another `201PracticalExcerise` folder within the directory, with the same files inside too. In other words, it creates a copy of the directory within itself.

Comment: Hmm don't know then, but it does seem a bit closer perhaps??? I'm up voting the question so it might get more attention from someone who's done this before... It's an interesting problem.

Comment: In your original question you say "when I moved those files to their  own folder I lost their commit history".  Did you use a "git mv" or just move them?

Comment: And did you make sure to follow the comment in the guide :  be sure to create at least one initial commit prior to doing the sub-tree merges.?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; seems I missed that step in the guide. I tried it on a couple repos and it works perfect. I'll do the rest when I can. If all goes well, I'll accept your answer.