# GitHub has 3 repos. I need to get these as subfolders of a new repo with each repo's history intact

Tags: windows, for-loop, github, git-extensions

The current repos are 'Execs', 'Web' and 'Database'
I would like to end up with a repo called BSM that contains the existing 3 as sub-folders. Current histories for all 3 should be maintained. Is this possible and how would I achieve this.
I have been reading mutiple results but I cannot get this to completion.
I am running VS2019 and use Git Extensions as a sanity check.

Comment: Presumably you have discounted the idea of managing these as submodules on BSM and wish to somehow merge all 4 repos together?

Comment: @johnfo - Yes, I dont think this is an option. There is too much interaction across all 3 repos and it will create the exact same problem that we are having now. Somewhere, sometime something will be left behind and we will start searching for work done but not brought forward. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: It seems I missed this discussion at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641867/merge-separate-git-repositories-into-one-repository-organized-by-folders?rq=1 . I am goig to research that solution and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the 'Web' repo contains libraries such as 'Common' and 'Data' which in turn carry common methods used by both 'Web' and 'Execs'. These libraries where orginally in their own repo under TFS but the move to GitHub has forced us to combine the 2 for exactly the same reason. BTW - I have tried the ....3164... example but did not get this to complete. There are just too many moves involved to keep track of this ( +- 4000 files in total in 150 odd folders). The problem here does not seem to be trying to get it right BUT the damage done if it fails and one needs to roll back.